# Mongoose ValidationError thrown instead of passed to callback,

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Mongoose has started throwing errors for me instead of passing them to my callback?

```
var newsArticle = new NewsArticle(fields);

newsArticle.save(function(err, newsArticle) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.status(201).json(newsArticle);
});
```

the callback is never called, and the ValidationError is thrown, crashing the app. Why is this?

```
events.js:85
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
No listeners detected, throwing. Consider adding an error listener to your connection.
ValidationError: NewsArticle validation failed
```

Comment: I think i might have been using an unstable version...